# Firebase callable function returns empty result

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am trying to access my firestore through a service account.
I can access the firestore online through an authenticated user with

```
const events = firebase.firestore().collection('event');
events.onSnapshot( snapshot => {
  let eventList = [];
    snapshot.forEach( doc => {
 eventList.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id});
});
console.log(eventList);
});
```

My steps:

1. I went into the firebase console and created a service account json and placed it into my functions directory
2. my package.json excerpt:

```
    "engines": {
      "node": "12"
    },
```

3. my function call from JS in my website to test the function:

```
const listEvents = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('listEvents');
listEvents().then( result => {
  console.log(result.data);
});
```

4. Initialize admin

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./debungleit-firebase-adminsdk-y7f39-b2147cf563.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "FROM-FIREBASE-CONSOLE"
});
```

5. access attempt 1:

```
exports.listEvents = functions.https.onCall( (data, context) => {       
    const snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('event').get();
    const events = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
    return events;
});
```

generates a parsing error after await: error  Parsing error: Unexpected token admin.

5a) Removing await lets me deploy the function, but on calling it I get a runtime error with the promise

6. attempt 2 to read an existing document:

```
exports.listEvents = functions.https.onCall( (data, context) => {
  return  admin.firestore().collection('event').doc('TfMHNZKyiWRL8YDodrim').then(snapshot => {
    return snapshot.data();
  });
});
```

throws an internal error on the firebase function that admin.firestore().collection('event').doc('TfMHNZKyiWRL8YDodrim').then is not a function

7. Attempt 3:

```
exports.listEvents = functions.https.onCall( (data, context) => {
    console.log('#1: Start of call');
    return  admin.database().ref('/event/TfMHNZKyiWRL8YDodrim').once('value').then(snapshot => {
        console.log('#2: Inside THEN promise');
        snapshot.exists? console.info('#3: snapshot exists') : console.info('#3 snapshot doesnt exist');
        (snapshot === null)? console.info('#4 snapshot contains data') : console.info('#4 snapshot = NULL');
        return snapshot.val();
    }).catch( error => {
        console.error('Error' + error.message);
        throw new Error('Error getting document:'); 
    });
```

This returns NULL. Here is the firebase function log:
6:47:06.229 PM
listEvents
Function execution took 1525 ms, finished with status code: 200
6:47:17.725 PM
listEvents
Function execution started
6:47:17.878 PM
listEvents
Function execution took 154 ms, finished with status code: 204
6:47:18.193 PM
listEvents
Function execution started
6:47:18.218 PM
listEvents
Function execution took 26 ms, finished with status code: 200
6:47:18.243 PM
listEvents
#1: Start of call
6:47:18.243 PM
listEvents
#2: Inside THEN promise
6:47:18.243 PM
listEvents
snapshot exists
6:47:18.243 PM
listEvents
snapshot = NULL

Now I tried all the suggested solutions and have no idea what to try next. Suggestions are welcome.

EDIT:
[image: firestore screenshot]

Comment: Perhaps there is no data the location of your query.  That's something we can't see here.   You might also learn more if you add some debug logging so you can be sure what's happening on each line.

Comment: Can you attach a catch block in the last attempt( Attempt 3) and see if there is any error.

Comment: For firestore screenshots, see above. The store has multiple docs with data.

I added logs into the code for attempt #3 and pasted the logs as well